# iptables redirecting for specific ip to port 8080

Tags: centos, iptables, port-forwarding

My PC has two IP addresses. How can I forward incoming requests on port `80` to `8080` from one of my IP using `iptables` in CentOS ?

For example, I have ip addresses `1.1.1.1` and `2.2.2.2`, I want to forward `http://1.1.1.1` port `80` to  port`8080` and just for `1.1.1.1` but not `2.2.2.2`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:8080
```